# Span dropdown select Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
    if ($(".x-span-drop-menu").css("display", "none")) {
        $(".x-span-drop-menu").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $(".x-span-drop-menu").css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

the dropdown menu drops down but it does not disappear again.
that is because I write it to Jquery
in Js it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$(".x-span-drop-menu").css("display", "none")` in the `if` condition you are setting css property and the function will return a *truthy* value so true block is executed, which make element visible again.

```
function myFunction() {
    var span = $(".x-span-drop-menu");
    if (span.css("display") == "none") {
        span.css("display", "block");
    } else {
        span.css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

I will recommend to use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) along with [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
function myFunction() {
    var span = $(".x-span-drop-menu");
    if (span.is(":visible") == false) {
        span.css("display", "block");
    } else {
        span.css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will be better to toggle css-class like `is-hidden` with styles:

```
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And as result you function will be:

```
function toggleFunc() {
    $(".x-span-drop-menu").toggleClass('is-hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery already, it may be simple to use a feature like [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$( ".x-span-drop-menu" ).toggle( display );
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( display === true ) {
  $( ".x-span-drop-menu" ).show();
} else if ( display === false ) {
  $( ".x-span-drop-menu" ).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle function to show and hide. Its simple

```
$(".x-span-drop-menu").toggle();
```